# c - printf c issues in terminal

Tags: c, ubuntu, terminal, printf

I have the following code in my main:

```
//testing with fork
printf("I am process: %d\n", getpid());
pid_t pid = fork();
printf("Now I am process: %d\n", getpid());
printf("fork returned %d\n", pid);
if(pid == 0){
    printf("I am child %d\n", getpid());
}
```

However the output on my terminal gives me this: 
[terminal output pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnvaV.png)

I run my program with a param of 'config_file.txt' as you can see on the first line, and the rest of it prints out fine until it hits the fork, and my cmd line comes up in between it...any ideas on why that is or how I can fix it? Is there something wrong with the code? I was just following a simple forking tutorial.

**Edit:** Also, after running it my program hangs there, and I have to hit enter to get my cmd line back up.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I have tweaked the English and bolded the "Edit".  This is done by using two asterisks around it.  Please take the effort to type in the text you see rather than using a link.  You have to put the effort in to make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: @RohitGupta Thanks for the info and the edit. As for the 'link', because I am still quite junior, Stack Overflow did not allow me to embed pictures into my post, and created a link for it instead. Since it is a terminal output, and it was seemingly erroneous terminal output, I felt that a picture of it would better inform anyone willing to help me out. Had it been an output wherein the issue was not related to the terminal itself, I certainly would have typed it out. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Based on that I have upvoted your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that the parent process is finishing before the child process.  When the parent finishes the prompt is displayed, however since the child is still running it continues to print output to the console.

If you want the parent to wait until the child is done, use the `wait()` function:

```
printf("I am process: %d\n", getpid());
pid_t pid = fork();
printf("Now I am process: %d\n", getpid());
printf("fork returned %d\n", pid);
if(pid == 0){
    printf("I am child %d\n", getpid());
} else {
    wait(NULL);
}
```

Comment: Ah, i see - thank you! I was following a youtube tutorial and that guy had no issues with the same code - guess his child finished before his parent.